# can I just make up a new protocol over ip?

Tags: protocols

Can I just make up a new protocol over ip? Or will that be blocked by the various routers, switches, firewalls etc. on the internet? Perhaps there is a governing body that permits/registers new protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I just make up a new protocol over ip?

Sure, if you really wanted to. There are a good number of IP protocols that are not TCP.

> Or will that be blocked by the various routers, switches, firewalls etc. on the internet?

It's more likely an ISP to block IP traffic it doesn't understand. However all of those components are free to block / allow protocols.

> Perhaps there is a governing body that permits/registers new protocols?

IANA controls the registrations of IP protocols. Their current is [available on their site](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml).

Keep in mind that it's unlikely that IANA would accept a new protocol without a very compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using the "protocol" over TCP, and that port gets banged at pretty good. Probably hackers trying to get in.